# Angle formed by 3 points in the complex plane knowing their affixes

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Q: What is the angle $\angle{A}$ formed by points $A(z_1)$, $B(z_2)$ and $C(z_3)$ in the complex plane?

How I did it:

Calculate the angle using dot product.

$\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC}=|\vec{AB}|\cdot|\vec{AC}|\cdot cos\alpha$

$\Big(\big(\underbrace{Re(z_2)-Re(z_1)}_{Re(z_2-z_1)}\big)\vec{i}+\big(\underbrace{Im(z_2)-Im(z_1)}_{Im(z_2-z_1)}\big)\vec{j}\Big)\cdot\Big(\big(\underbrace{Re(z_3)-Re(z_1)}_{Re(z_3-z_1)}\big)\vec{i}+\big(\underbrace{Im(z_3)-Im(z_1)}_{Im(z_3-z_1)}\big)\vec{j}\Big)=|z_2-z_1|\cdot|z_3-z_1|\cdot cos\alpha$

Observe how $z_2-z_1$ and $z_3-z_1$ repeat. Let's try these notations:

$
\begin{cases}
\Delta_1=z_2-z_1 \\
\Delta_2=z_3-z_1
\end{cases}
$

Then $cos\alpha=\frac{Re(\Delta_1)Re(\Delta_2)+Im(\Delta_1)Im(\Delta_2)}{|\Delta_1|\cdot|\Delta_2|}$.

$Re(\Delta_1)Re(\Delta_2)+Im(\Delta_1)Im(\Delta_2)=Re(\Delta_1\bar\Delta_2)$

$cos\alpha=\frac{Re(\Delta_1\bar\Delta_2)}{|\Delta_1|\cdot|\Delta_2|}$

Is this always correct?

Comment: More directly: $\;\alpha = \arg \Delta_1 - \arg \Delta_2=\arg \frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2}=\arg \Delta_1 \overline{\Delta_2}\,$, so $\cos \alpha =\frac{\Re(\Delta_1\overline{\Delta_2})}{|\Delta_1|\,|\Delta_2|}\,$.

Comment: Not strong on complex analysis (I'm in highschool) but could understand your solution!

Comment: No need to make a special edit, but this isn't complex geometry. If you edit the post in the future, please remove the tag. :)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Fixed. I thought complex geometry means generally the study of complex number in the carthesian plane.

Comment: The meanings of tags can be found by clicking the "Tags" item near the upper left corner of the screen (in Chrome --- maybe elsewhere in other browsers).

Comment: Thanks Neox; it's a natural thing to think, and no harm done. :)